# Six figures (3x2) on one page using subcaption package?

Tags: captions, subcaption

I want to have 6 figures on one page distributed on 3 rows and 2 columns. I've tried using `\begin{subfigure}` in the subcaption package without any luck. The figures are displayed correctly, but any text I add to the document is placed before the page with the figures and not after.

Any suggestions?

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{{.5\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.37]{fig/benchmarkcase/2VF1CAD5.PNG}
  \caption{5 CAD}
  \label{fig:VF1CAD5}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.37]{fig/benchmarkcase/2VF1CAD25.PNG}
  \caption{25 CAD}
  \label{fig:VF1CAD25}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.37]{fig/benchmarkcase/2VF1CAD50.PNG}
  \caption{50 CAD}
  \label{fig:VF1CAD50}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.37]{fig/benchmarkcase/2VF1CAD75.PNG}
  \caption{75 CAD}
  \label{fig:VF1CAD75}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.37]{fig/benchmarkcase/2VF1CAD100.PNG}
  \caption{100 CAD}
  \label{fig:VF1CAD100}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.37]{fig/benchmarkcase/2VF1CAD120.PNG}
  \caption{120 CAD}
  \label{fig:VF1CAD120}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Volume fraction fuel phase}
\label{fig:VF1BMC}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: The whole sixpack is a single figure hence if TeX doesn't like the position, it will change its position and it is expected depending on where you are trying to place the figure. Maybe a good way to understand why it is so is to look at Frank Mittelbach's excellent description which guaranteed to save you a lot of time and frustration later [how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-latex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)